Could this code be written in a better way?
For r As Integer = 1912 To 1996 Step 12
    zodiac = "Rat"
    If uYear = r Then
        MsgBox("Hi " & userName & ", your chinese zodiac is " & zodiac)
    End If
Next
For o As Integer = 1913 To 1997 Step 12
    zodiac = "Ox"
    If uYear = o Then
        MsgBox("Hi " & userName & ", your chinese zodiac is " & zodiac)
    End If
Next
For t As Integer = 1914 To 1998 Step 12
    zodiac = "Tiger"
    If uYear = t Then
        MsgBox("Hi " & userName & ", your chinese zodiac is " & zodiac)
    End If
Next

The goal is to display different zodiac names based on the user's birth year.
uYear is a variable that stores the user's selected birth year that was taken from a combo box.
Ex:
if the year is 1912, 1924, 1936, 1948, 1960, 1972, 1984, 1996 then the output will be a Rat.
if the year is 1913, 1925, 1937, 1949, 1961, 1973, 1985. 1997 then the output will be an Ox.
Etc...
I haven't tried anything because I can't figure a out to a way to better write the code.
I thought of using nested loops but can't figure out how to construct it.

Why your years end with 1998? It continues, so your code doesn't work for people born after 1998. Your code also doesn't take into account that there is a time gap in the year dates between lunar calendar(used for the zodiac chart) and Gregorian calendar.

what if you take (uYear-1912)%12, you have a lookup to the sign
